# Angular 2 Routing Children and router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'am using routing with children which should be loaded in separate outlet.
All the components are placed directly inside the /app folder.

app.router.ts:

```
export const router: Routes = [

    { path:'dashboard', canActivate:[AuthguardGuard], component: DashboardComponent },
    { path:'', component: LoginComponent },
    { 
        path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, 
        children: [
           { path:'features', component: FeaturesComponent, outlet: 
           { path:'signup', component: SignupComponent, outlet: 'content' },
           { path:'more', component: MoreComponent, outlet: 'content', 
           { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
       ]
    }
];
```

dashboard.component.html:

```
<a [routerLink]="['./']">Overview</a>
<a [routerLink]="['features']">Features</a>
<a [routerLink]="['details']">How To</a>
<a [routerLink]="['more']">SignUp</a>
<a [routerLink]="['signup']">SignUp</a>
```

When loading the app under: `http.//localhsot:4200`, I first start with a login component/page (loaded in unnamed router-outlet as default) which checks a user and pass. After that it goes to dashboard component/page (using AuthguardGuard). URL is then: `http://localhost:4200/dashboard`
From the dashboard page I want to be able to navigate to other pages/components, and they should be loaded in the outlet:"content"

app.component.ts:

```
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="mdl-layout__tab-panel is-active" id="overview">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</main>
```

I have been trying few suggestions found here on the platform, but none of them did help. e.g.:
`<a [routerLink]="['signup', {outlets: {content: 'signup'}}]">SignUp</a>
 <a [routerLink]="['../signup']">SignUp</a>`

But it didn't work... different errors like:
`Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'signup'`

Any Idea what I'am doing wrong or what should I change or add please?

Comment: did my answer solved your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. same Error: `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'signup'`

Comment: have you found any fix for this as i am having same problem. But for me ['/dashboard',{outlets: {content:'signup'}}] worked. but it created a URL which i cant use.

Comment: @PraveenRawat: Yes, working fine now fine. Could you please post the generated URL which you can't use. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fix for this is very difficult. Try to define an empty path in your routerlink like this

```
[routerLink]="['', {outlets: {content: 'signup'}}]">SignUp</a>
```

You defined your named outlet at the app.component.html that's why the path is empty

**Update 1**

The reason why the named router does not show up with your children routes is because your named router is in the same template with your Dashboard like this

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
```

The error here is that your "content" router is on the same level with your  "main" router where the dashboard will show up. The "content" router should be inside of dashboard.component.html and **NOT** in your app.component.html. Just copy paste the `<router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>` inside your dashboard.component.html and it should work.

Comment: Trying your suggestion without children part, the empty path works with the outlet named "content". Here the changes I did:

`export const router: Routes = [
    { path:'signup', component: SignupComponent, outlet: 'content' },
    { path:'', component: LoginComponent },
    { 
        path: 'dashboard',  canActivate:[AuthguardGuard], component: DashboardComponent, 
        children: [
           { path:'features', component: FeaturesComponent, outlet: 
           ....
       ]
    }
];`
But I want to solve it with the children... is the any other solution?

Comment: @k.vincent it's possible. wait for my answer